# Energy band diagram of a metal-silicon-metal device, bias voltage applied

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I have an intrinsic silicon layer sandwiched in between two aluminum contacts. I'm trying to figure out the band diagram of the entire device when a positive bias (much larger than the work function of the aluminium) is applied to one of the contacts. Intuitively, I would expect the i-layer part to be tilted (like in a p-i-n device), but I can't figure out what the connections between the i-layer and the metal contacts looks like.

Comment: This was asked a while ago but is a good and interesting question I hope it gets a response. I would start by drawing this in equilibrium (flat Fermi-level) then you need to decide if you form Ohmic or Schottky contacts with the metal and also specify the Schottky barrier height.